# Detect browser in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, backwards-compatibility

I need to know (on .rb/.haml level) if device is mobile or if browser is not supported. I don't want (or it won't work well for my need) to parse userAgent on client side.

Answer (score 4):

Gem [browser](https://github.com/fnando/browser) seems to be what I exactly need. It is mainly used in Rails and I could not find the fully correct snippet for Sinatra, so I share my solution:

```
require "browser"

...

get "/"
  browser = Browser.new request.user_agent, accept_language: request.env["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]
  break haml(:mobile, locals: { reason: "you are mobile" }) if browser.device.mobile?
  break haml(:mobile, locals: { reason: "you are not chrome" }) if not browser.chrome?
  ...
  haml :index
end
```

Comment: Are you aware that the `browser` parses the user agent too? I thought that was not an option, because that would not work well for your needs?

Comment: @spickermann, it was not an option to parse userAgent *on client side* -- when some html and js already had to be loaded. I wanted to recognize browser before giving out the content. Oops, forgot the imporant line of code -- updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do

 request.user_agent

end
```